# Numeric value of CMP 16bit register ,16bit register

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I need to open COM file and find "CMP AX, BX" from that file. I am stucked , i guess that i need to compare CMP instruction's machine code. So i need to know numeric value of CMP.

Comment: did you try assembling it and disassembling it to see what you got?  Or did you look at the instruction set reference?  what did you find when you did that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use an online assembler**
You can easily find this using an online assembler, like: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm

**Specifically**
On the original 8086 it's

```
39 D8   CMP AX,BX
```

On the 80386 and above it's

```
66 39 D8  CMP AX,BX + 16 bit operand size override.
```

**Instruction decoding**
The instruction decodes as follows

```
66 -> 16 bit operand size override
39 -> CMP R16, R16
D8 -> = binary 11 011 000
               ||  ||  ++--- AX = reg0
               ||  ++ BX = reg3 
               ++--ModRM code for pure register operands, no memory
```

See: http://ref.x86asm.net/geek.html#x00
At the bottom where it says: `32-bit ModR/M Byte`
The x86 decodes registers in octal form in the order:

```
  AX  CX  DX  BX  SP  BP  SI  DI
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
```

The first two bits of the ModRM byte are:

```
00: [reg] : memory addressed by reg with no offset
01: [reg+8-bit offset]: memory addressed by reg with 8-bit offset
10: [reg+32-bit offset] memory addressed by reg with 32-bit offset
11: reg: just the register.
```

The instruction opcode specifies whether the modrm byte that follows is  `source, dest` or `dest,source`.

Comment: "On the 80386 and above it's 66 39 D8" Not necessarily (only needed in protected mode code), and in the case of the OP where he's looking in a .COM file, highly unprobable!

Comment: @Fifoernik, I'm answering the general question.

Comment: Even so. With any processor you can find both forms in a file.

Comment: @Fifoernik, which is why I included them.

Answer (score 1):

The value of CMP will vary according to the operand.

It may be, in hexadecimals:

mnemonics

```
39 - CMP     Reg, Reg
3A - CMP     Regb,Memory
3B - CMP     Reg,Memory
3C - CMP     AL,Byte
3D - CMP     (E)AX,Immediate

80 - CMP     RegByte,Immediate Byte = 80
81 - CMP     Memory,Reg = 81 
83 - CMP     Reg/Mem,Immediate (sign extended) byte
```

See this for more details:
http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#cmp

Comment: That's a link only answer. You should expand on it.

Comment: Much better, but I cannot upvote 'cause you missed `39` and `83`. See: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html

Comment: :) No problem at all @Johan... My wish is only to provide a help for those whom, for so many times, had helped me too...

Comment: Thank you @Johan - it is really much better now. Thanks!!